# check all checkboxes of parents jquery doesn't work in bootstrap menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, siblings, closest

I'm trying to check all checkboxes by clicking on the parent checkbox
but this code doesn't work for ul segment below

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        $(this).siblings('ul')
            .find("input[type='checkbox']")
            .prop("checked", this.checked);
        });
    });
<script>
```

and if I use closest instead of siblings it checks all the checkboxes in subs no matter who the parent is.

```
<nav class="main_navigation navbar navbar-default vertical_nav_enable" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li class="dropdown">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                    <a href="/cat1"  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Cat1
                    </a>
                </label>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox"/>
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/subcat1">
                                SubCat1
                            </a>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox"/>
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/subcat2">
                                SubCat2
                            </a>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox"/>
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/subcat3">
                                SubCat3
                            </a>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                    <a href="/cat2"  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Cat2
                    </a>
                </label>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox"/>
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/subcat4">
                                SubCat4
                            </a>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox"/>
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/subcat5">
                                SubCat5
                            </a>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox"/>
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/subcat6">
                                SubCat6
                            </a>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        $(this).closest('li')
            .find("input[type='checkbox']")
            .prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));

    });
});
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/arekp4no/)

I updated solution in this link.

Answer (score 0):

found it!
using parent() before siblings

```
 $(function () {
        $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {

            $(this).parent().siblings("ul") 
                .find("input[type='checkbox']") 
                .prop("checked", this.checked);

        });
    });
```